# Get Facebook Events to RSS feed

Tags: json, facebook, events, rss

How to get all events as Rss for a user from Facebook. I tried below link but it giving only one event not all.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=643795265635061
```

I could not find any link to get all events for the user. Is there any way to get all events in RSS or Json format.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can no longer do this thanks to the wonderful people at Facebook:

> Events, Groups, Pages and Instagram APIs will no longer be available to new developers
>
> apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

Answer (score 5):

Events can be [exported](https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178/) in popular calendar formats (Apple iCal, Microsoft Outlook, Google Calendar) but unfortunately there is no public feed! To retrieve an event feed as JSON, you need to have an [access_token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/). You can test it easily via [Facebook's Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=taakeofficial/events/):

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=taakeofficial%2Fevents%2F`

When implementing it programatically (or serving your own up-to-date feed), you'll need to use one of the [Facebook SDKs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) (PHP, for a server) and add your access_token to the query:

`https://graph.facebook.com/taakeofficial/events?access_token=ABC123`