# Get posts from Facebook Event Page as RSS feed

Tags: facebook, rss

Is there a way to retrieve all posts from a Facebook Event page as an RSS feed? It should be similar to getting a fan page as RSS which works with the URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20
```

but if I fill in my event ID here it would not work. Does anyone know the correct URL for doing that?

It should be for example grabbing all posts on a site like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/events/244382585623944/
```

When just inserting the event ID into PAGE_ID a "Facebook Syndication Error" is returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Facebook Events to RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921227/get-facebook-events-to-rss-feed)